# How do you create a complex custom component in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

I'm having a hard time getting something to work, and I'm beginning to wonder if it's even possible?

How would you create a custom component that has nested custom components?

For example, I'd like to create a date-range-picker using ng2-bootstrap's datepicker. I have a use case that requires an optional duration element (disabled input with unit of time addon, e.g. 'days'). Is it possible to create a component that looks something like the following?

```
<calendar [value]="startDate"><calendar>
<calendar [value]="endDate" [minDate]="startDate"><calendar>
<div class="input-group">
  <input disabled type="text" [value]="duration">
  <span class="input-group-addon">{{ unitOfMeasure }}</span>
</div>
```

In this example, I'm using a custom component for the ng2 datepicker, called calendar. It could just as easily be the native ng2 datepicker instead.

What I'd ultimately like to do is bind to the start & end dates, as well as the duration (possibly have an IDateRange { start: Date, end: Date, duration: number }). Is that possible?

All examples I've seen using the ControlValueAccessor are for single values, and I'm not sure if I can do a complex value like described above?

I'm on vacation and trying to make this quick. If more details are needed, please let me know. I'll respond as soon as I can. This is something I've been struggling with for a little while, and haven't been able to find any examples for the kind of use-case I need.

Thanks!

Comment: You can only bind a single value to a single control using `ngModel`, but the value can be a complex value like `{ start: Date, end: Date, duration: number }`

Comment: Thank you, Gunter. That's what I thought, but I'm having trouble understanding the implementation, I guess. Would the nested controls - in this case, the calendars & duration input - look something like this? <input disabled [value]="value.duration">

Comment: You could bind one like `[(ngModel)]="value?.start` and the other like `[(ngModel)]="value?.duration`.

Comment: Wow, that was a fast response! Thank you, Gunter!